# Can't upload files in Google Chrome - Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, kde, upload

I recently installed Kubuntu 19.10 (and Plasma Desktop 5.18) on my main laptop. I installed the necessary packages like

`kubuntu-restricted-extras`

`kubuntu-restricted-addons`

And also installed Google Chrome and made it my default browser.

The problem I'm having is that, I can't upload some specific file formats like PDF's, the service that I use the most is Google Drive, and every time i try to upload i file (drag-n-drop, or selecting it), I get an error which is `File unreadable` or `Rejected by server`, this also happens on WhatsApp Web.

But i tried to do the same things on Firefox and it works just fine, so I think is definitely a Google Chrome problem

I want to mention that I have enabled the GDrive integration in Dolphin, and I can upload files through Dolphin just fine.

I saw an answer to a similar problem on a forum, and it said:

> The path where the documents were saved contained a letter with a caron. I removed it and it all works now!

But I don't know what does that refer to.

I had previously installed Ubuntu 19.10 (Gnome) and never had an issue, so i think is a problem about how KDE handles files and paths. Ithink is a problem between Dolphin and Chrome, because Firefox uses the GTK file chooser

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Skadlig never haha, I ended up moving to other distro and desktop. But I'm sure this had to do something between chrome and plasma, dunno if got fixed